# how to debug the code which is running under task server in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, daemon, starling-server

In rails have a code which is running under task-server and starling server. I want to know what's the recommended way to debug the code line by line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can use [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug). Install the gem and put "byebug" where you want to debug the code.